# managed c++ syntax

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++

Try as I might, I cannot convert this Managed C++ code to C++/CLI.  Can someone give a pointer (pun intended)?

```
static String *ignoreStrings[];
```

Later in the code, an Add(string) method is called on it.  Elsewhere, in some C# code,

```
new String[]{"foo", "bar"}
```

is passed into a function that is somehow cast into the type of ignoreStrings above.

I've tried this syntax:

```
static array<String^> ^ignoreStrings;
```

But it can't cast from that C# array, and it doesn't have an add method either.

---

Edit:  More complete code in the hopes that this changes the question somehow...

```
private:
    static String *ignoreStrings[];

public:
    void AddIgnoreString(String *ignore)
    {
        AddOneIgnoreString(ignore);
    }

    void SetIgnoreStringData(String *ignore[])
    {
        SetIgnoreStrings(ignore);
    }

    static void SetIgnoreStrings(String *ignore[])
    {
            ignoreStrings = ignore;
    }
    static void AddOneIgnoreString(String ^ignore)
    {
        ignoreStrings->Add(ignore);
    }
```

Elsewhere, from C# code, this call is made:

```
SetIgnoreStrings(new String[]{"foo", "bar"});
```

This is what I tried to convert the C++ code to:

```
private:
    static array<String^> ^ignoreStrings;

public:
    virtual void AddIgnoreString(String ^ignore)
    {
        AddOneIgnoreString(ignore);
    }

    virtual void SetIgnoreStringData(array<String^> ^ignore)
    {
        SetIgnoreStrings(ignore);
    }

    static void SetIgnoreStrings(array<String^> ^ignore)
    {
        ignoreStrings = ignore;
    }

    static void AddOneIgnoreString(String ^ignore)
    {
        ignoreStrings->Add(ignore);
    }

    static array<String^> ^GetIgnoreStrings()
    {
        return ignoreStrings;
    }
```

Comment: Could you use the Reflector to see what type is generated from "static String *ignoreStrings[];" and what the IL code is that was generated from the "ignoreStrings->Add(ignore);" line? I don't think that ignoreStrings is a .NET array but rather an ArrayList, List<T> or something similar. Because a .NET array does not have a Add() method!

Answer (score 2):

Your try

```
static array<String^> ^ignoreStrings;
```

should work!

.NET arrays do not have an Add method (not in C++/CLI or C#!).
If you mean a List (which has an Add() method) then it would be

```
static System::Collections::Generic::List<String ^> ^ignoreStrings;
```